# How to reference three columns that have dates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that needs to recognize the date in the column of my google sheets. I want to reference three columns but I can only do that with one column.

```
function getRecords()
{
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CrossTAB SAP");
  var recordsRange = recordsSheet.getDataRange();
  var recordsValues = recordsRange.getValues();  

  var colunadata = 0;  //ALTERAR
  
  for(var i = 0; i < recordsValues.length; i++){          
        
        var data = new Date(recordsValues[i][colunadata]) ;      

          data.setDate(data.getDate());

        var d = data.getDate();
        var m = data.getMonth();
        var a = data.getFullYear();
        
        if(d < 10){
          var d = "0" + d;
        }

        if(m < 10){
          var m = "0" + m;
        }

        var data = d + "/" + m + "/" + a                

        recordsValues[i][colunadata] = data; 

}

  return recordsValues;

}
```

I tried to add two vars (columndata2 and columndata3) and add to the code but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide an input example for the dados variable and the expected output please? I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: I have a script in google apps that needs to recognize the format date in my google sheets. I add a full code to show better.

Comment: Thank you, but we DO need to see some data and an example of the outcome that you are trying to achieve. As it stands, this statement: _I want to reference three columns but I can only do that with one column._ is vague and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used this library, so maybe my solution will not be optimal or functional.

But, you can test the following code, by interating into the `recordsValues[i]` array with a for loop.

```js
function getRecords()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("CrossTAB SAP");
  var recordsRange = recordsSheet.getDataRange();
  var recordsValues = recordsRange.getValues();  

  var colunadata = 0;  //ALTERAR
  
  for(var i = 0; i < recordsValues.length; i++){          
    for(let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        var data = new Date(recordsValues[i][j]);

        var d = data.getDate();
        var m = data.getMonth();
        var a = data.getFullYear();
        
        if(d < 10){
          var d = "0" + d;
        }

        if(m < 10){
          var m = "0" + m;
        }

        var data = d + "/" + m + "/" + a                

        recordsValues[i][j] = data; 
    }
  }

  return recordsValues;
}
```